# Portable Class Libraries and WebBrowserTask vs Windows.System.Launcher

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, launcher, portable-class-library

I'm assuming that the answer is simply no, but just in case... Is there any way of executing platform-specific code in a PCL?

My specific example lends itself nicely to a PCL. The vast majority of code is fully supported using profile104 (WP7/Windows Store/Net40). The only bit which is platform specific is the ability to launch a deep-link:

```
my-custom-protocol://some/url
```

The non-shared code is:

```
On WP7, it would be:
        WebBrowserTask web = new WebBrowserTask();
        web.Uri = BuildUrl();
        web.Show();

On WP8 and Windows Store it would be:
        Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(BuildUrl());

On Net40, I guess you would host a web-browser control.
```

So the common library provides custom "Task" objects which provide the implementation of "BuildUrl()". The issue is that on a supported device, you want to launch "my-custom-protocol://some/url", but on any other device you want to go to a web fallback http://mysite.com/some/url. This is all wrapped up in:

```
        new CustomTask(data).Show()
```

- Option 1 (Current implementation): Don't use a PCL, and use #ifdefs in the CustomTaskBase class to contain the platform specifics. However, I really don't want to have to maintain platform-specific project files with cs files added as links :-(
- Option 2: Just put the launchers in platform specific assemblies, with all the other code in a PCL. Again, I don't like this, as it seems maintenance-heavy, and doesn't reduce our project count. It also means that clients need to reference two assemblies, rather that one, which seems overkill for a few custom tasks.
- Option 3: Inject an abstracted IPlatformSpecificLauncher into the constructor of the Launcher, which then becomes a URLBuilder. This moves the launch-code into the client, which would be copy-paste (although minimal). It does however complicate the API and makes it less readable.

  ```
      new CustomTask(new WP8Launcher(), data).Show()
  ```
- Option 4: Change the API so that the CustomTask simply returns the URL to launch (and again have the launching code in-client). But then how would you implement the web-fallback on devices which don't support the custom protocol? You cant say if(platform == WP7) in the PCL, can you?

Thank you in advance of any hints and tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For platform-dependent functionality in a PCL the obvious answer (other than giving up) is dependency injection of some sort, or using a service locator. Your example seems to me to be a good use of DI in general, even ignoring the actual limitations of PCLs - you really are plugging in different behaviour.

"Platform enlightenment" ala RX is another approach (good overview of all these approaches [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/portable-class-library-enlightenment.html)), where the PCL loads additional assemblies via reflection.

In either case you'll increase your project count. I think there's an argument that putting as much into a PCL as possible and separating out platform-specific functionality into separate small chunks is cleaner than a big shared library which is linked from multiple projects, where the distinction between shared and #if-conditional code is less obvious.

As to the question "can you say if (platform == WP7)", your PCL can't contain platform-conditional code, though a PCL could target a subset of platforms all of which contain the required functionality.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd never heard of "Platform Enlightenment", just reading about it now. BTW - This is a nice article: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/portable-class-library-enlightenment.html

Comment: Great answer.  @JonRea: As far as clients needing to reference two assemblies, you can package everything up into a NuGet package that can be referenced as a single unit.

Comment: @Daniel - Yeah, we are using NuGet internally. It's a great tool. This enlightenment stuff sounds like a plan :-)

Comment: I've made a little demo project - it works really well. You can get the code here if you are interested: https://github.com/JonnyWideFoot/pcl-enlightenment